# How to make the buttons responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to move my buttons to right and make it responsive. Please can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:

I am using background image in CSS here

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!--   Background image and Buttons -->
    <div style="background-image:url('images/image.jpg'); padding-bottom: 30%;background-size: 100% 100%;" class="wrapper">
      <div id="homebuttons" class="container">
        <!-- Login with a button -->
        <button style="top:170px; width:25%;" id="logintl" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical" title="Login with MiiSky" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Login with SATMP</button>
        <br>
        <!--   Register with a button  -->
        <br>
        <br><a href="register.html" style="top:200px; width:25%" id="registertl" title="Register with MiiSky" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Register with SATMP </a> 
      </div>
      <!-- End homebuttons container-->
    </div>
    <!-- End Background image-->
```

My buttons are at the right but it is not responsive.

**Current Output:** 
      Buttons are moving out of the image as shown in the image below...
      I want to fit the image so that it should not be altered even if the browser size is reduced.
      Any idea would be helpful
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Dty.jpg
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uL7G.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibhCa.png

Comment: 1) get out of using inline styling. Use an external css instead. 2) You have a type with `width=25%`. It should be `width:25%`.

Comment: that is correct... but my buttons are moving out of the image how to make it fit within the image? so that even if i reduce the browser size it should fit, within the image?

Comment: don't use a `px` value for your `top` declaration. use `%` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what you want. Basically, here's what I did.

1. Removed the inline CSS style from button and anchor tag.
2. Removed the width property.
3. Added class **bt1 and bt2** to the buttons.
4. bt1 and bt2 were style with **top:100px and top:120px** respectively. You can change the pixel to whatever height you want.

Below is my working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        About TechGenium
    </title>

    <!-- Font-Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

            <!-- language: lang-html -->

            <!--   Background image and Buttons -->
            <div style="background-image:url('images/bg_3.jpg'); padding-bottom: 30%;background-size: 100% 100%;" class="wrapper">
              <div id="homebuttons" class="container">
                <!-- Login with a button -->
                <button id="logintl" type="button" class="bt1 btn btn-info btn-lg sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical" title="Login with MiiSky" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Login with SATMP</button>
                <br>
                <!--   Register with a button  -->
                <br>
                <br><a href="register.html" id="registertl" title="Register with MiiSky" type="button" class="bt2 btn btn-info btn-lg sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Register with SATMP </a> 
            </div>
            <!-- End homebuttons container-->
        </div>
        <!-- End Background image-->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.bt1{
    top: 100px;
}
.bt2{
    top: 120px;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Replace the background image to whatever image you have and the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

## html

Here is my final code with modification:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

                <!-- language: lang-html -->



<!--   Background image and Buttons -->
            <div style="background-image:url('images/bg_3.jpg'); padding-bottom: 30%;background-size: 100% 100%;" class="wrapper">
              <div id="homebuttons" class="container">
                <!-- Login with a button -->
                <button id="logintl" type="button" class="bt1 btn btn-info sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Login with SATMP</button>
                <br>
                <!--   Register with a button  -->
                <br>
                <br><a href="register.html" id="registertl" type="button" class="bt2 btn btn-info sharp pull-right btn-group-vertical"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> | Register with SATMP </a>
            </div>
            <!-- End homebuttons container-->
        </div>
            <!-- End Background image-->
        </div>
```

## css

Here i changed the width of my buttons so it worked perfectly for me!!

```
    <style>
    .bt1{
        top: 50px;
        width:230px;
        color: black;

    }
    .bt2{
        top: 51px;
        width:230px;
        color: black;
    }
    </style>

    </body>
```

**Final Output:**
    [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sLcS.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyWgh.png)
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBTEg.png)